# How to generate report like pivot table from php 3d array on question_id base

Tags: php

Actually I am generating a report and print out answers under that question id. Like 13377 questiin id answered 3 times so i want to echo their answers underneath and the same for other question ids. All data is dynamic. Get unique questions id that will be table head and all answers of that id will be underneath. Its like pivot table report. So I am not getting the logic how to do that.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 13377
            [add_more_counter] => 0
            [front_title] => Text question
            [value] => first time fill
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [question_id] => 13377
        [add_more_counter] => 0
        [front_title] => Text question
        [value] => second time fill
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [question_id] => 13377
        [add_more_counter] => 0
        [front_title] => Text question
        [value] => text question 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [question_id] => 13378
        [add_more_counter] => 0
        [front_title] => Text box 2
        [value] => text question 2
    )
)
```

and i want to transform into this

```html
<table border="1"><tbody><tr><th>13377</th><th>13378</th></tr><tr><td>firt time fill</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>second time fill</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>text question 1</td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td>text question 2</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to iterate index using keys.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over keys keeping index constant,

```
$a = []// Your array
// considering all array have same keys
$keys = array_keys($a[0]);
echo "<table>";
foreach ($keys as $value) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
        echo "<td>".$a[$k][$value]."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks for you feedback but its not that what i want. Actually i want to print table head and table cell dynamically and put all data under question id that is same as you can see in output (table)

Comment: It is just how you should iterate, html is not big deal. You can surely come up with solution.